# Discord py how to get list of cogs?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have slash commands under some cogs, and I would like to create a custom help command to list cogs, groups, and commands. However, I've only been able to grab all the commands via `client.tree.walk_commands()`. How do I loop through cogs and groups to get the commands?

Comment: Just use `client.cogs`.